# Prolog: Using member on a list within a list

Tags: recursion, prolog, append, member

For an assignment we have to essentially check if a member of one clause is a member of a list in a list. For example:

```
person(p1,[a,c])
```

and the task `task(t1,a)`.

I understand you can use member to see something like member(a,[a,c]). But how would I go at checking for (what I assume is the tail) in another clause?

After figuring out that, I was wondering if I could have a nested functor for a conditional? My program is starting to look something like this:

```
schedule(Person,Task,RESULT):-
        member(<person's list>,<task's list>) -> append(<person's head>,<member's head>,RESULT).
```

`schedule` is the functor I'm making and it'll recurse through the list of task clauses, and checking to see if there is an appropriate person for the task (by matching that part of the clause). Eventually, I'll output a list of the tasks (`t1`-`t6`) and the people who can complete them.

Sorry  if my terminology is off.

Thank you!

Comment: @lurker: `memberx(X, Xss) :- member(Xs, Xss), member(X, Xs).`

Comment: @false, ah yes. Thanks. That's much more tidy. Thanks.

Comment: @lurker: It means also that you do not need a  predicate definition + name at all, since you can write these two goals directly

Comment: @false, indeed. It's quite simple. Thanks.